# Anonymous function as parameter

Tags: scala

```
def fun(f: Int => Unit) {
  f(10)
  f(20)
}
println("method 1 call:")
fun(i => {println("hi"); println(i)})
println("method 2 call:")
fun{println("hi"); println(_)}
```

The output is:

```
E:\test\scala>scala i.scala
method 1 call:
hi
10
hi
20
method 2 call:
hi
10
20
```

I think `i => {println("hi"); println(i)}` and `println("hi"); println(_)` are the same. Because we have one parameter and the parameter is used just once, we can use `_` to simplify the code.

Then, why does method 2 just print "hi" once?
(Does it mean: if I want to use `_` to simple the calling, the contents on the right of `=>` just can have one expression, if have more than one, e.g. println("hi"); println(i); Then, we can not use `_` to replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to know that in scala `{ block; of; code }` is an expression that evaluates to whatever the last expression inside it evaluates to.

When you say:

```
fun(i => { println("hi"); println(i) })
```

you create an anonymous function, which body contains 2 expressions, both returning `()` and both are evaluated when function is called, everything as expected.

But when you say

```
fun({println("hi"); println(_)})
```

You pass in a block, not an anonymous function. As sepp2k explained this expands to

```
{ println("hi"); x => println(x) }
```

So, you pass a block to `fun`, this block is being evaluated before it is passed. So first `println("hi")` happens, it is printed just once as block is evaluated once, and then this `x => println(x)` is evaluated, which is a function `Int => Unit`, that prints its argument. This, and only this (as a last expression is passed to the `fun`. This is why each time you call `fun` it just prints the argument twice.

To see further on how block could work you can look at this example that does more in the block

```
fun {
  println("building the function")
  val uuidOfThisFunction = UUID.randomUUID
  x => println(s"$uuidOfThisFunction, $x")
}
```

So this block prepares a function giving it some extra context through the closure. This uuid will stay the same for both calls that happen if `fun`.

```
building the function
86e74b5e-83b5-41f3-a71c-eeafcd1db2a0, 10
86e74b5e-83b5-41f3-a71c-eeafcd1db2a0, 20
```

The example that would look more like what you did with first call would be

```
fun(
  x => {
    println("calling the function")
    val uuidOfThisCall = UUID.randomUUID
    println(s"$uuidOfThisCall, $x")
  }
)
```

The block evaluates every time `f` is called.

```
calling the function
d3c9ff0a-84b4-47a3-8153-c002fa16d6c2, 10
calling the function
a0b1aa5b-c0ea-4047-858b-9db3d43d4983, 20
```

Answer (score 4):

`println(_)` expands to `x => println(x)`, so `{println("hi"); println(_)}` expands to `{println("hi"); x => println(x)}`. So when `fun{println("hi"); println(_)}` executes, the following steps take place:

1. The expression `{{println("hi"); println(_)}}` is evaluated. Which means:

   1. `println("hi")` is evaluated and then
   2. `x => println(x)` is evaluated, creating a function object that will print its argument.
   3. The thus-created function object is the result of the expression.
2. The method `func` is called with the created function object as its argument. `func` will call the function with `10` and `20`, causing it to print those numbers.

Comment: I think you just gived the description of the result, not the reason. As the definition of `def fun(f: Int => Unit)`, what's the `f` in the definition of `fun{println("hi");println(_)}`? if `println("hi")` is not included in `f`, why?

Comment: Yes, this is what I really want to know. In fact, I want to realize the effect of  method 1 call, meanwhile I want to simple the calling "fun(i => {println("hi"); println(i)})". So I used method 2 call, but find the effect is quite different from method 1 call. So I want to get the real reason, why println("hi") is not included in f in method 2 call?

Comment: @atline I believe I gave the real reason. `{println("hi"); println(_)}` does not expand to `{x => {println("hi"); println(x)}}`, but rather to `{println("hi"); x => println(x)}`. And that's why you see the behaviour you see. The reason it expands that way is that the expansion rules are pretty simple. For this case the relevant rule is simply that `f(args...,_,...moreArgs)` expands to `x => f(args..., _, ...moreArgs)`. If you want to know why the rules are as they are, you might ask the designed, but it probably boils down to that simple rules tend to be better, having to look at the ...

Comment: ... context of the expression complicates the expansion code (and logic) by quite a bit and it'd be impossible to match the programmer's intent in all cases anyway. Plus: the more complicated the rules, the harder it is for the programmer to understand what a given piece of code will expand to, even if he does know the rules.